# Excel Pivot Advanced How to incorporate multiple columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a table that looks like this -

```
Key |    X      |    Y      |     Z
    |  Date     |   Date    |    Date
1a  | 01-Jan-16 | 15-Jan-16 |
2a  |           | 01-Feb-16 |   
3a  |           |           | 01-Mar-16
```

I need to do a pivot on this table, to get a resulting table that looks like this -

```
Key   |   Type   |   Date
1a    |     X    | 01-Jan-16
1a    |     Y    | 15-Jan-16
2a    |     Y    | 01-Feb-16
3a    |     Z    | 01-Mar-16
```

I've tried multiple versions of Pivot, but they don't get me all the data within these 3 columns. What might the best solution be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the row with `Date`. Insert copies of your `Key` column immediately to the left of your `Y` and `Z` columns. Add two adjacent columns at a time using [Multiple consolidation ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120), drill-down on the `Grand Total` intercept and filter the `Value` column to delete rows with blank cells. Label as appropriate.

Comment: Excellent! Just what I was looking for! Thanks a ton! :)